# What is the command to search a content in all the model fields at once?

Tags: django, search, filter, searchbar

I am developing an app with Django.
I have developed a search bar to filter the database contents.

I want that, when the user clicks on the search button, the indicated content is searched in all the model fields.
My model has 16 fields, so my filter command will be a very long line, like:

```
selected_entries = glossary_entry.objects.filter(Q(field1__icontains=query)  | Q(field2__icontains=query)) | ...ETC ETC... | Q(field16__icontains=query))
```

Here you can see this line in my view function, in *views.py*:

```
def glossario(request):

    query = request.GET.get('q') 
    template = "glossario.html" 
    # query applied
    if query:

        query = request.GET.get('q') 
        selected_entries = glossary_entry.objects.filter(Q(field1__icontains=query)  | Q(field2__icontains=query)) | ...ETC ETC... | Q(field16__icontains=query))

        return render(request, template, {'all_entries':selected_entries})

    # no query
    else:

        all_entries = glossary_entry.objects.all 
        return render(request, template, {'all_entries':all_entries})
```

Is there a shorter command to do the same?
Like:

```
selected_entries = glossary_entry.objects.filter(Q(ALL_MODEL_FIELDS_ICONTAINS(model=MyModel)=query))
```

**Note:** `ALL_MODEL_FIELDS_ICONTAINS` is my invention

Answer (score 1):

You will have to specify all the fields anyway. There isn't a shortcut. But you could [concatenate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#concat) all fields and just do one lookup:

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Value as V
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

glossary_entry.objects.annotate(
    search_string=Concat(
        'field1', V(' '), 'field2', V(' '), 'field3', ...,
            output_field=CharField()
        )
    ).filter(search_string__icontains=q)
```

Note: I've added spaces between each field using `Value` although that's not strictly necessary with `icontains`, it just helps with debugging if you're looking at the value of `search_string`.